How to balance a node tree without causing circular dependencies?
I have a node tree with approximately 200 nodes and want to reduce the number of nodes.
The tree has a root node, and each node can point (import) to one or more of the other nodes.
I am able to merge the nodes if merging them does not cause a circular dependency.
The general idea is I want to get x number of nodes and make their size as balanced as possible.
I have tried to implement a greedy algorithm multiple times, but always end up causing circular dependencies.
I am looking for some advice/direction as to what an optimal solution for this problem would be.
As a realistic example, I want to merge the nodes so that there are approximately 5 nodes left.

In less abstract terms, the issue I am trying to solve is https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/27715#issuecomment-2217435573
I have a file that contains the information about all the nodes, and need to generate a map that contains x number of new nodes and the nodes that they merge.

This is a reduced example of a data type in typescript:
type Nodes = {
  [name: string]: {
    bytes: number;
    imports: string[];
  }
}

lets say i have a the following nodes:
{
 "a": {
  "bytes": 100
  "imports": ["b", "c"] 
 },
 "b": {
  "bytes": 50
  "imports": ["d"]
 },
 "c": {
  "bytes": 50
  "imports": ["b"]
 }
 "d": {
  "bytes": 100
  "imports": []
 }
}

I would now have these links:
a -> b
a -> c
a -> d beacuse (a -> b -> d)
b -> d
c -> b
c -> d beacuse (c -> b -> d)

Now if I was to merge the nodes a and d it would cause a circular dependency:
{
 "ad": {
  "bytes": 200
  "imports": ["b", "c"] 
 },
 "b": {
  "bytes": 50
  "imports": ["ad"]
 },
 "c": {
  "bytes": 50
  "imports": ["b"]
 }
}

because now our links look like this:
ad -> b
ad -> c
b  -> ad
c  -> b
c  -> ad beacuse (c -> b -> ad)

As you can see there are now circular dependencies between the new ad and b, and consequently between ad and c.

I’m not sure exactly what the setup is and what merging means. In the picture it looks like the graph already has loops. Can you provide some simple examples with a small number of nodes?

@NickAlger I added some info, let me know if there is more i should add.

You could topologically sort your graph and then group the resulting list into contiguous chunks. This will never create cycles.

@Chris Thanks for adding the info. I second Karl's suggestion to do a topological sort. You can do this with depth first search.

@Karl How would that work. If i do a topological sort i end up with a list this list would simply contain all the items and would not prevent me from merging items break  the DAG.
Or what am i missing?

If you merge contiguous blocks of items in the topologically sorted list, it won't create a cycle.

I'm curious about the application, though. Are these code bundles loaded lazily on demand by the web client? Should they consist of logically related modules?

The issue is not with lazy modules but with import-statements and code splitting https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/3780.

Unfortunatly my understanding of DAG and Topological Sort is not great at the moment. Will need to do more investigation to figure out how to make this work for my use case. But the principal seems sound.
